# PHP: Redirect but continue to process script with ignore_user_abort(true) fails

Tags: php

I have problem that I cannot figure out. It seems to be a server related issue.

What I need to do is - when user is submitting form, he is redirected immediately to some page, but PHP script continues to process all form data in background.
The code is like this:

```
//if form is submitted start:
//redirect user
header("Location: activity.php");

ob_end_clean();
header("Connection: close");

ignore_user_abort(true);

set_time_limit(1800); //extend process time

ob_start();
header("Content-Length: 0");

ob_end_flush();
flush();

session_write_close();

//Below this line starts the code to process form.
```

When testing this code on local server everything works as expected, user is redirected to page `activity.php` and PHP script continues to run in background. When uploading the same script to live server, nothing works. User is not redirected, and the page waits until everything is processed and only then redirects the user to `activity.php`.

Why is it so? I cannot see any mistake in this script. Can anyone please help?
Is there some package that needs to be enabled on server? I cannot understand why this script works on one server but fails on other. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: don't forget that php has no control of what happens upstream of it. if that other server has a proxy/caching server in front of it, php cannot force that upstream device to do its own flushing.

Comment: Check gzip is not enabled.

Comment: If you're on a shared host, it can be there is a buffer you can't change. Als `flush()` is not working with `fast-cgi`, so in that case you should find another way.